# Is there any difference between \` and backquote?

Tags: eval, backquote

I was surprised to find that if I use `M-x ielm`, I get a literal backquote:

```
ELISP> (read "`foo")
`foo
```

However, if I use `` M-: (read "`foo") `` then `*Messages*` and the minibuffer show `` (\` foo) ``.

Are these two equivalent? Why doesn't `` (equal (read "`foo") `foo) `` return `t`?

Comment: `ielm` is pretty printing, similarly, ``M-x pp-eval-expression RET (read "`foo") RET`` will show `\`foo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *value returned* by the sexp `` (read "`foo") `` is `` `foo ``.

You are confused by the form of the *printing* of the read value by the
command you are using (`eval-expression`, bound to `M-:` by default).  What it prints is a *Lisp representation* of the value.  If you instead use `pp-eval-expression` then you see `` `foo ``, which is the (same) value printed for *humans*. (This is one of several reasons that I prefer to bind `M-:` to `pp-eval-expression`.)

As for the Lisp representation - in library `backquote.el` you see this Commentary (notice the first line):

```
;; When the Lisp reader sees `(...), it generates (\` (...)).
;; When it sees ,... inside such a backquote form, it generates (\, ...).
;; For ,@... it generates (\,@ ...).
```

That first line could have said that when it sees `` `... `` it generates `` (\` ...) ``. In other words, what is says is not just for a backquoted *list*.  In your case, when it sees `` `foo `` it generates `` (\` foo) ``.

And `` (equal (read "`foo") '`foo) `` does return `t`.  (You forgot to quote the second argument to `equal`.  You used `` `foo `` as the second argument, but that gets evaluated - to `foo`, not to `` `foo ``, which is what you wanted to compare with the value of `` (read "`foo") ``.)